# How to generate an ICE candidate?

Tags: javascript, web, webrtc

I'm developing a video conference with WebRTC in a local network, so I use only one signaling server to exchage SDP data. As I understand, I also need to exchange ICE candidates, but I don't know how to generate them. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the generated iceCandidate by setting the peerConnection.onicecandidate event.

```
(async () => {
  const pc = new RTCPeerConnection();
  pc.onicecandidate = evt => {
    console.log(evt.candidate?.candidate);
  };
  const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video:true});
  stream.getTracks().forEach(track => pc.addTrack(track, stream));
  const offer = await pc.createOffer();
  await pc.setLocalDescription(offer);
})();
```

Comment: I've tried doing that, but that event never commited

Comment: I think the event will fire when run peerConnection.setLocalDescription().

Comment: Yes, I use peerConnection.setLocalDescription(), but event doesn't fire

Comment: Are you adding MediaStreamTrack (addTrack ()) or creating a DataChannel (createDataChannel ()) in peerConnection?
Or, in case of offer for receive only, did you pass offerOptions in setLocalDescription()?

Answer (score 0):

Do you create a configuration which contains at least one ice server url, and then use this configuration to create your RTCPeerConnection instance? When you set an ice server url, the 'icecandidate' event should be fired.

```js
const configuration = { 
  iceServers: [{ urls: "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302" }],
};
const pc = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);
pc.addEventListener('icecandidate', event => {
  if (event.candidate) {
      console.log('icecandidate received: ', event.candidate);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

*(Here are my thoughts/guesses 

(I wish I know more of the internal source code of Webrtc))*

#### get ice_candidate & STUN & internal source code

> *(As another answer post pointed out)* 
>
> && 
>
> [] 
> An **`icecandidate`** event is sent to an [`RTCPeerConnection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection) when:
>
> - An [`RTCIceCandidate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCIceCandidate) has been identified and added to the local peer by a call to [`RTCPeerConnection.setLocalDescription()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/setLocalDescription),
>
> <> 
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/icecandidate_event \

So, I ***think*** the getting of ice_candidate are **in the internal source code** 
-- **which happens inside `RTCPeerConnection.setLocalDescription()`** 
the `source code` talk with `STUN` & emit `icecandidate event` to `pc.onicecandidate` on each found ice_candidate?<

#### send ice_candidate & Trickle ICE

> Trickle ICE in WebRTC - YouTube 
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oIDYLwaalcs

> []
>
> ```js
> pc.addEventListener( 
>   "icecandidate", 
>   (e) => pc.canTrickleIceCandidates && sendCandidateToPeer(e.candidate), 
> );
> ```
>
> <> 
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/canTrickleIceCandidates \

I think ice_candidate were sent with Offer at the same time in the old days?< 
But now, with Trickle ICE, ice_candidate should be able to be sent even after the Offer was sent?< \

- (I guess it stops when the best ice_candidate is found during `pc.addIceCandidate(candidate);`?<)

#### misc note

- (Of course, I assumed that you have correctly setup your STUN & TURN server,) 
  eg::

  ```
  const rtcConfig: RTCConfiguration = {
    iceServers: [
      {
        urls: ['stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302', 'stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302'],
      },
    ],
  };
  const pc = new RTCPeerConnection(rtcConfig);
  ```

#### more info

> [] 
> When starting a WebRTC peer connection, typically a number of candidates are proposed by each end of the connection, until they mutually agree upon one which describes the connection they decide will be best. WebRTC then uses that candidate's details to initiate the connection. 
> <> 
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCIceCandidate \

> [] 
> Typically, each peer will propose its best candidates first, making their way down the line toward their worse candidates. 
> <> 
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Connectivity \

> [] 
> When a website or app using [`RTCPeerConnection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection) receives a new ICE candidate from the remote peer over its signaling channel, it delivers the newly-received candidate to the browser's [ICE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/ICE) agent by calling **`RTCPeerConnection.addIceCandidate()`**. This adds this new remote candidate to the `RTCPeerConnection`'s remote description, which describes the state of the remote end of the connection. 
>
> If the `candidate` parameter is missing or a value of `null` is given when calling `addIceCandidate()`, the added ICE candidate is an "end-of-candidates" indicator. The same is the case if the value of the specified object's [`candidate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCIceCandidate/candidate) is either missing or an empty string (`""`), it signals that all remote candidates have been delivered. 
>
> The end-of-candidates notification is transmitted to the remote peer using a candidate with an a-line value of `end-of-candidates`. 
> <> 
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/addIceCandidate \